# HTMX get the text from inputfield for using in hx-get

Tags: django, django-templates, alpine.js, htmx

```
 <input type="number" x-model="inputValue" min="1" max="{{ page.paginator.num_pages }}"
           placeholder="Enter a number">
<button type="button" hx-get="?page={{ ????? }}">Go</button>
```

here is the code extending it from the htmx example to create a go to page for partial load pagination
https://github.com/adamchainz/django-htmx/tree/main/example

The problem is that I am not able to configure hx-get to take the value of inputValue field.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to populate the parameters with Django template interpolation, but that is server-side, and the value is only known on the client-side.

Instead, you need to tell HTMX what values to grab from the client side, to include in the `GET` request. You can do this with the [hx-include](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-include/) attribute. You also need to add a `name` attribute to the `input` element:

```
<input name="page" type="number" x-model="inputValue" min="1" max="{{ page.paginator.num_pages }}" placeholder="Enter a number">
<button type="button" hx-get="" hx-include="[name='page']">Go</button>
```

Comment: <input  name="goto_page" type="number">
       <a href="?page=" type="button" hx-get="?page=" hx-include="[name='goto_page']">Go</a>

What am I doing wrong? the goto_page is not being included. even with hx-include.

Comment: @AdnanNazir I just tested your code, and it submits the value like this: `?page=&goto_page=3` If you go back and copy/paste the code from my answer directly, it will work, and submit the value as `page` in the GET request. The way you are doing it, you will have an empty `page` attribute, and a separate `goto_page` attribute with the actual value.

Comment: Mark many thanks for your reply. I tried but its still not working.